# Grid How To Convert Lambert Conformal To Latitude/Longitude

Tags: grib, pygrib

I have a grib data about WRF.

The grid definition template number is 30 ( Lambert Conformal )

But now, I need to convert this lambert conformal to 0 (  Latitude/Longitude )

Is there possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes
You need to get the package wgrib2, http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/

and then just run

wgrib2 `<input_file>`  -new_grid_winds grid -new_grid_interpolation neighbor -new_grid latlon 198:450:0.02 18:300:0.02 `<output_file>`

Where, of course, you need to set appropriate coordinates for your particular domain.

The coordinate definition 198:450:0.02 means:
198 -- longitude
450 -- number of points
0.02 -- grid step in degrees.

And the order is longitude, latitude.

Comment: which parameter is my lambert grb2 file? also wtha's "198:450:0.02 18:300:0.02" mean?

Comment: @FrankLiou Sorry, I had some bad formatting so input/output where lost in the view. Corrected this and also added explanation about grid. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have read the wgrib document, and I got the answers too.  but your detailed description is so helpful, but I have some confused about "-new_grid_interpolation neighbor" and "-new_grid_interpolation bilinear", what's different and which one is suit on me?